# Drupal module for custom contact form into sql

Tags: php, drupal

I'm looking for a drupal module that pushes contact form submissions straight into mysql; then allow the admin to view it. Any out there, or better to just write it myself?

Comment: Drupal has its own site now: `http://drupal.stackexchange.com/`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [Webform](http://drupal.org/project/webform). Form builder that stores submissions, can email them, or all sorts of other nifty things. Well-tested, used just about everywhere.